.NET 8, Identity, Bearer issue
I'm building a web app (an authoritative server that will be used for a game I'm building) using ASP.NET Core 8, and I'm utilising Microsoft's Identity to do all authorisation and authentication.
Using Postman for testing Identity's AddIdentityApiEndpoints endpoints I'm able to successfully login a registered user, which returns:
{
    "tokenType": "Bearer",
    "accessToken": "CfDJ8...",
    "expiresIn": 3600,
    "refreshToken": "CfDJ8..."
}

Using the accessToken (I'm assuming this is what's required for the Bearer token's value within Postman), I attempt to hit an endpoint that right now does nothing but the controller's behind an [Authorize] tag. However I'm always getting 401 unauthorized.
Program.cs:
public class Program
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         //CREATE WEBAPP BUILDER
         var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

         builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>(options =>
         {
             options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
             options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
             options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
             options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
             options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
         })
            // .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MM_DbContext>();

         builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
         {
             options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
             options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
             //options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
         {
             options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
             {
                 ValidateIssuer = true,
                 ValidateAudience = false,
                 ValidateLifetime = true,
                 ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                 ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                 IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Key"]!))
             };
         });

         // ADD SERVICES - DI ALLOWS TEST / NONTEST SERVICES
         builder.Services

             .AddScoped<Services.IArmouryService, Services.TestArmouryService>()
             //.AddScoped<Services.IAuthenticationService, Services.TestAuthenticationService>()
             .AddScoped<Services.IBattleboardService, Services.TestBattleboardService>()
             .AddScoped<Services.ICharacterService, Services.TestCharacterService>()
             .AddScoped<Services.IKingdomService, Services.TestKingdomService>()
             .AddScoped<Services.ISoupkitchenService, Services.TestSoupkitchenService>()
             .AddScoped<Services.ITreasuryService, Services.TestTreasuryService>();

         // POSTGRESQL CONNECTION
         builder.Services.AddDbContext<MM_DbContext>(options =>
             options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db")));
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Connection String: {builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Db")}");

         // ADD CONTROLLERS
         builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(o => { });

         // ADD SWASHBUCKLE/SWAGGER
         builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
         builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

         // NEW WEBAPP
         var app = builder.Build();

         app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();

         // USE SWAGGER IF DEVELOPING
         if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
         {
             app.UseSwagger();
             app.UseSwaggerUI();
         }

         // MISC
         app.UseAuthentication();
         app.UseAuthorization();
         app.MapControllers();

         // RUN
         app.Run();
     }
}

KingdomController:
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("newmap")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IMapNewResponse>> NewMap([FromBody] MapNewPayload payload)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    try
    {
        var result = await _kingdomService.NewMap(payload);

        if (result is IMapNewResponse)
        {
            return Ok(result);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "Unexpected error occurred"); //incorrect error code - unsure how to handle 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"New map failed: {ex.Message}");
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
}

I'm quite new to web servers and identity framework, as you can see in the code blocks I've submitted, I've already implemented a rudimentary Authentication system, but the time it would've taken me to iron out all of the features that Identity already provides out of the box just didn't seem worth it, I wanted to continue with developing the game, not an authentication/authorisation system.
I'm unsure what else to try or how to proceed.

Your access-token "CfDJ8..." is not a JWT - if it was it would start with eyJ - so that might be why the JwtBearer auth middleware is rejecting them.

I note that "CfDJ8..." indicates a value encrypted by ASP.NET's DataProtection system

You need to uncomment the //options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; line too.

@Dai Hmm you are right, it's not a JWT, I read in the ms docs Identity generates an "opaque" token rather than a JWT. And I suppose program.cs is registering and configuring functionality to process a JWT.

When accessing an [Authorize] endpoint with a JWT token. Make sure that the JWT is correctly added to the Authorization header as Bearer  in Postman. Verify your token's Issuer and SigningKey match the configurations in Program.cs. Check the token's claims and expiration. Ensure UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() are in the correct order in the middleware pipeline. Enable logging for detailed error info, and test via Swagger or Postman.

you probably need to use  IdentityConstants.BearerScheme.

I've got it working as following
Basically the token generated is for Identity.Bearer
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.BearerScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.BearerScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.BearerScheme;
}).AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);


